# Are there any Gaudiya Vaishnava commentaries on the Upanishads?

Tags: upanishads, adi-shankaracharya, resource, gaudiya-vaishnavism

Sri Adi-Sankaracharya's commentaries on the Upanishads are most popular in present time. Are there any Gaudiya Vaishnava commentaries available on the Upanishads?

Comment: ISKCON has one Ishopanishad so far as i know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I do know of a commentary on the Katha Upanishad, authored by **Swami B.V. Giri**, which adheres to Achintya-Bheda-Abheda. Unfortunately, the book is not available online. You can buy it [**here**](https://www.amazon.in/Katha-Upanishad-Swami-B-V-Giri/dp/8192660141).

**Edit 1**: I found commentaries written by **Sri Bhakti Prajnan Yati Maharaj** free online on the Taittirya Upanishad, Aitareya Upanishad and Chandogya Upanishad. You can read them [**here**](https://archive.org/download/Acc.No.4682TwelveEssentialUpanishads/Acc.No.4682-Twelve%20Essential%20Upanishads.pdf).

Also, you might be able to purchase all the twelve Upanishadic commentaries authored by Sri Bhakti Prajnan Yati Maharaj [**here**](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/m/book/details/twelve-essential-upanishads-two-volumes-isha-kena-katha-prashna-mundaka-mandukya-chandogya-brihadaranyaka-svetasvatara-and-gopalatapani-upanishads-old-and-rare-book-with-original-sanskrit-text-transliteration-translation-and-purport-IDI966/).

**Edit 2**: You can also read **Baladeva Vidyabhusana**'s commentary on the Isha Upanishad free in **Hindi** [**here**](https://archive.org/download/Isopanisad.KrsnadasBaba/Isopanisad.Krsnadas%20Baba.pdf). By the way, Baladeva Vidyabhusana also wrote commentaries on other Upanishads but none of them survived.

**Edit 3**: You can also read **A.C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada**'s commentary on the Isha Upanishad [**here**](http://wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/isha-upanishad-prabhupada).

**Edit 4**: I found all the Upanishadic commentaries of **Sri Bhakti Prajnan Yati Maharaj** online. You can read it [**here**](http://radha.name/sites/default/files/documents/1518/Twelve%20Essential%20Upanishads.doc).

Comment: Thanks..I ve been searching non-advatic commentaries on Upanishads since a while now...it really makes me wonder why non- advaitic vedantic schools focus on other scriptures despite upanishads being a part of prasthantrayi...

Comment: There is no need to add edit 1, 2 , 3 in answer.

Comment: @RishX  The schools of philosophy post Sri Sankara period are called "bhakti vedanta schools" by some scholars, especially the scholars in Ramakrishna mission. The Sankara school is called Vedantic school by the same scholars. The reason is, by Sri Sankara's system the connection between metaphysics and deity worship is somewhat flexible. But if you compare that with Sri Yamunacharya, Sri Ramanujacharya, and Sri Madhva schools, they standardized on a very specific deity in addition to creating a philosophical framework. Sri Madvacharya has commented on all the Upanisads like Sri Sankara did.

Comment: Though Sri Ramanuja used Upanisads in His bhashyams, His Holiness did not comment on all the Upanisads and portions of The Veda. Among the acharyas the extensive Vedic commentary is found in Sri Sankara and Sri Madhva's works. Other Acharyas either did not write a dedicated commentary, or selectively commented here and there. The reason, if you ask me, is their respective approach of being prescriptive about single deity worship along with The Vedic backing. This could have, possibly limited the scope of Vedic passages in their work, especially if their goal was prescribing a system of worship